# Malloc returns the same pointer twice

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I allocate dynamic array in main like this:

```
char *arr = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

then in a random function I reallocate that array to n elements like:

```
arr = realloc(arr, n * sizeof(char));
```

then I do a random stuff with the array, and in another function I want to allocate one more array with n elements like this:

```
char *arr2 = malloc(n * sizeof(char));
```

but this malloc returns the same adress as arr. I tried everything, but still returns the same adress, so arr2 is pointing to arr. What am I doing wrong?
If i allocate new array again lets say arr3 with the same method, now it works and it gives me new adress.

Edit:

```
void reallocate(char *arr, int newLength) {
    arr = realloc(arr, newLength * sizeof(char));
}

void fc1 (char *arr, int *length) {
    char *temp = malloc(*length * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(temp, arr);

    int d;
    scanf("%d", &d);

    char *arr2 = malloc(d * sizeof(char)); //there it gives me the same adress 
    scanf("%s", arr2);
}

int main(void) {
    char arr = malloc(sizeof(char));
    int *length = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *length = 10;

    reallocate(arr, 10);
    fc1(arr, length);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us all of your code, not just the isolated parts.  What you're describing doesn't seem possible, which means you've left out some critical details.

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can duplicate the problem and thereby help you debug it

Comment: it can be possible when `n` is zero.

Comment: does strcpy free the source array?

Comment: You have `char *arr` as an argument to `reallocate()` and when it does the `realloc()` you do not get the pointer to the new memory area provided by `realloc()`. You need to either return the new pointer by making `reallocate()` a `void *` return rather than `void` and then return `arr` or you need to make `arr` a pointer to a pointer (`char ** arr`) and do the dereferencing properly as in `*arr = realloc(*arr, newLength * sizeof(char));`.

Answer (score 1):

We'd need to see the code to be sure, but here's two ways it can happen:

```
 void func2(char *s)
 {
      do_something(s);
      free(s); // we are done with it
 }

 void func1(void)
 {
      char * array = some_func();
      func2(array); // Oops, func2 frees it
      char * array2= malloc (...); // could get the same pointer
 }
```

Here, `func1` passes the pointer to `func2` which frees it. It is an error for `func1` to do anything with `array` after that point as it can be re-assigned.

And the second way:

```
 void get_data(char *s)
 {
      char *data = // code to get some data from somewhere
      s = realloc (s, strlen(data) + 1);
      strcpy(s, data);
 }

 void func1(void)
 {
      char *ptr = malloc(12);
      get_data(ptr);
      // oops, ptr has the old value
      char *ptr2 = malloc(12); // could get the same pointer
 }
```

Here, `get_data` calls `realloc` but the caller still has the old pointer which `realloc` might free.

But we'd need to see the code to be sure.

**Update**:

I guessed right. This is the second way in my example above:

```
void reallocate(char *arr, int newLength) {
    arr = realloc(arr, newLength * sizeof(char));
}
```

This looks exactly like my `get_data` function above. This function does not pass the new value of `arr` back to the caller, so the caller still has the old value which may be freed.

```
reallocate(arr, 10);
fc1(arr, length);
```

This looks exactly like my second `func1` above. You pass `arr` to `reallocate` which may invalidate it, but then you pass the old value of `arr` to `fc1`. But `reallocate` may have freed it. There's a reason `realloc` returns the new value, but your `reallocate` function doesn't.